# Variable operations in array index

Tags: php, arrays, variables, indexing

I would like to know if its possible to, for example add a number to array index value like this, without declaring it first:

```
$arr[$ix+1]
```

Comment: in any other language can you do like this??

Comment: [Why not try it and see](https://3v4l.org/5WViq)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: haven't tried in no language,  it would save me so much time in my situation right now

Comment: i tried, not working, i would like to know if there is some way, and yes I know that there is php documentation

Comment: to clarify, 
$sql2 = "UPDATE kontaktai SET kon_vardas='$data[$c+1]', kon_pavarde='$data[$d]', WHERE kon_epastas='$kontakto_vardas'";  
 
i get unexpected '+', expecting ']

Comment: Stop right there..... don't interpolate data values in an SQL statement.... use prepared statements/bind variables..... there's no excuse, it's 2015, not 1995

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible:

```
$ix = 1;
$arr[$ix+1] = 1;
```

It will declare an array and set it's index `$ix+1` to 1.

Not possible:

```
$ix = 1;
$arr[$ix+1];
```

In this case it will try to return `$arr[$ix+1]` which is not defined.

Comment: to clarify, $sql2 = "UPDATE kontaktai
                                SET 
                                    kon_vardas='$data[$c+1]',
                                    kon_pavarde='$data[$d]',
                                    
                                WHERE kon_epastas='$kontakto_vardas'";

Comment: i get  unexpected '+', expecting ']

Comment: You cannot use operators inside double quotes. Only variables are allowed. So `$c+1` is not possible.

Comment: Thank you! I'm so overworked right now...

Answer (score 0):

add element to array

```
$arr = array();
for($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
  $arr[] = $x;
}
var_dump($arr); 

array(11) { 
[0]=> int(0) 
[1]=> int(1) 
[2]=> int(2) 
[3]=> int(3) 
[4]=> int(4) 
[5]=> int(5) 
[6]=> int(6) 
[7]=> int(7) 
[8]=> int(8) 
[9]=> int(9) 
[10]=> int(10) }
```